# MATLAB: Four Digit Rounding Arithmetic

Tags: matlab

I'm having trouble trying to get MATLAB to make a calculation using four-digit rounding arithmetic.

(Unfortunately, since I am new to Stackoverflow, I can't post images, so I'll need to link externally to what I initially set up in this question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joYht.png)

However in MATLAB, when I try to use the function vpa, I receive the answer -0.01611.

Here is the MATLAB script I am running:

```
A = 1;
B = 62.10;
C = 1;

vpa((-B+sqrt(B^2-4*A*C))/(2*A),4)
```

Which returns

```
ans =

-0.01611
```

When I want

```
ans =

-0.02
```

Am I using the function vpa incorrectly? Is there a better way to formulate the quadratic equation in my MATLAB script to achieve this? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow!  If you receive an answer that works for you, please remember to "Accept" it.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the result from the picture, you have to do what's done there, round after each operation and not only once at the end. Unless you need the extended precision from `vpa`, I recommend to use doubles instead and use [`roundsd`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26212-round-with-significant-digits/content/roundsd.m) instead.

```
%just demonstrating it for the first intermediate result, getting the 3852
r=@(x)roundsd(x,4)
r(B^2)-4*r(A)*r(C)
```

Putting the rounding operation everywhere is not very convenient, for a more convenient use you may implement your own class, overloading the built in operators.

Comment: I appreciate the help Daniel! I opted to use round(x,4,'significant') initially, but I couldn't find any documentation on MATLAB on how to shorten that so my code wasn't so unreadable. I've implemented it now using r=@(x)round(x,4,'significant') and it works! Thanks =)

Comment: Note that `round` has this functionality built-in since a few versions of MATLAB

Comment: I am using Matlab 2013a, did not notice it changed in recent versions.

Comment: I'm not sure when they implemented it earlier; I answered a similar question here writing my own `round` function, then someone commented it as well to me. `ceil` and `floor` don't have the functionality however, so for those two `roundsd` is still the way to go I think

Answer (score 0):

Use the `round()` function:

```
A = 1;
B = 62.10;
C = 1;

x = vpa((-B+sqrt(B^2-4*A*C))/(2*A),4)
x =
      -0.01611
y = round(x,2)
y = 
      -0.02
```

Comment: The issue is I need to use this in a bigger script that will generally calculate different formulas that may not always round to the second position after the decimal.

For example, if I were to apply the equation x^2 - sqrt(7)x + sqrt(2)

The approximation of x is: 1.902346481...

Using four digit arithmetic I would get an answer of 1.903 (rounded up from 1.9029).

Unfortunately, round(x,2) would not give me the answer I need in this case.